# jsonPath predicate to return the whole JSON

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I would like to return the whole JSON if a condition is matched.

Test Json:

```
    {
            "EVENTID": 2624367601,
            "RECEIVERNAME": "CM.MYHR",
            "SENDERNAME": "CM.EIS.CF1",
            "AGREEMENTNAME": null   
    }
```

I keep trying in https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com, but couldn't figure it out.
I thought the following expression should work, but it always return empty.

```
$.[?(@.SENDERNAME==CM.EIS.CF1)]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You only have a fragment of a json. Try it like this:

```
{
  "events": [
{
            "EVENTID": 2624367601,
            "RECEIVERNAME": "CM.MYHR",
            "SENDERNAME": "CM.EIS.CF1",
            "AGREEMENTNAME": null   
    }

]
}
```

And use:

```
$.*[?(@.SENDERNAME=='CM.EIS.CF1')]
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Since I can't change my input JSON format which is not an array, does it mean I can't use jsonPath filtering which works on ARRAY only? Any alternatives or workaround on filtering a plain json?

Comment: @Autorun - You can do that (or something like that) using python and a couple of json and jsonpath libraries; they can process your original test json without needing to modify it. I can give you more info (or post an answer) if that's relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want while json as it is from input, then as per my understanding you have to use below expression:

```
$.
```

I have tested it in https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/